# Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated

Tags: python, android, sdk, kivy, buildozer

I am using Buildozer to make an App from my python/kivy file. After running this command line:

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

I have this error:

```
WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
No compiled python is present to zip, skipping.
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Error while running "/home/kouhi/kouhi-company/idea4/1/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 -OO -m compileall -b -f /home/kouhi/kouhi-company/idea4/1/.buildozer/android/app"
This probably means one of your Python files has a syntax error, see logs above
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --debug --bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name myapp --name 'My Application' --version 0.1 --package org.test.myapp --minsdk 21 --ndk-api 21 --private /home/kouhi/kouhi-company/idea4/1/.buildozer/android/app --android-entrypoint org.kivy.android.PythonActivity --android-apptheme @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar --orientation portrait --window --copy-libs --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir="/home/kouhi/kouhi-company/idea4/1/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
```

I am using ubuntu. Let me know if you need any more information

The syntax error I found in the terminal are:

```
***   File "/home/kouhi/kouhi-company/idea4/1/.buildozer/android/app/buildozer/android_ndk/android-ndk-r20b/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/smtpd.py", line 123
except socket.error, err:
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

***   File "/home/kouhi/kouhi-company/idea4/1/.buildozer/android/app/buildozer/android_ndk/android-ndk-r20b/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 330
except socket.timeout, e:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

***   File "/home/kouhi/kouhi-company/idea4/1/.buildozer/android/app/buildozer/android_ndk/android-ndk-r20b/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/python2.7/Bastion.py", line 103
raise RuntimeError, "This code is not secure in Python 2.2 and later"
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

based on these, I guess the main problem is that I have two version of python on my linux (python2 and python3). For kivy, I have to use python3.  I think the buildozer does not understand it while I have python2.7 folder in buildozer.
What should I do to let buildozer just use python3 and not python2?

Comment: The error is pretty explicit: This probably means one of your Python files has a syntax error, see logs above

Comment: @inclement . Thanks for your reply. If it means that my python/kivy code has a problem, I am sure about the code and it works fine when I compile it as a python3 code.  if not, I do not understand the meaning and I do not know what to do.

Comment: To quote the error message again: **see logs above**. The information you need is not in the part you pasted.

Comment: @inclement  wooww, thanks, Yes I got it and I found the syntax errors in the terminal... The first three sytax errors are added to the body of the question. I think the main problem is that I have two versions of python (2 and 3) on my laptop and to run python 3 (which is proper for kivy) , I have to use "python3 file.py".  So, maybe this is the problem. Am I right?

Comment: Interesting, p4a is picking up Python 2 files from inside the android ndk. This makes me suspicious that you may accidentally be including these or something, the files have apparently been present in all recent NDKs and I've never seen this issue.

Comment: @inclement  so, do you think if I have to clean all NDK versions on my laptop and then let the command line ("buildozer android debug deploy run") install it again?

Comment: you could not choice one version of python,it is NDK's bug

Comment: how do you solved that? Please comment your answer because I am using only python3 and it throws the same error using buildozer build

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will solve your problem becuase I have the same error while using Python3. But to remove doubt in your situation you can specify the version of Python in the buildozer.spec

First, use the command:
python3 --version

Mine returns: Python 3.11.4. Once you know your python version, open buildozer.spec and find the line starting with 'requirements'. Should be something similar to:
*requirements = python3,kivy*

after python3 type == and then the version you are using:
*requirements = python3==3.11.4,kivy*

This should force the use of that version of python.

Like I said, mine is already coded to use a specific version, and I still have the issue you are having with the --sdk argument.